# ModelChoiceField Validation Error when Dynamically Disabling Field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hi all I have the following form defined as below. If it is a form that is being passed a `fte_assignment` object and if it is not `None` I then want to disable the user field which seems to be working. The issue is when I submit the form I get the following field error `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.` I'm wondering what can I change so that the field is still disabled put will pass validation? Below I include the needed form definition information and the call from the view.

`forms.py`

```
class TeacherForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location = kwargs.pop('location', None)
        self.end_year = kwargs.pop('end_year', None)
        # fte_assignment gets passed in if it is an edit this helps
        # with when to fire off our clean method logic
        self.fte_assignment = kwargs.pop('fte_assignment', None)
        super(TeacherForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # THIS IS WHERE I DISABLE THE FORM
        if self.fte_assignment:
            self.fields['user'].disabled = True

    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        label='Employee',
        queryset=User.objects.all()
    )
    room = forms.CharField(max_length=6)
    extension = forms.IntegerField()
    job = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Job.objects.all()
    )
```

`views.py`

```
fte_assignment = FTEFutureAssignment.objects.get(pk=fte_id)
form_kwargs = {
    'user': fte_assignment.user,
    'room': fte_assignment.room,
    'extension': fte_assignment.extension,
    'job': fte_assignment.job
}
form = TeacherForm(
    request.POST or None,
    initial=form_kwargs,
    location=location,
    end_year=end_year,
    fte_assignment=fte_assignment
)
```

`teacher_form.html`

```
    <form
        method="post"
        novalidate
        action="
            {% if not fte_assignment %}
                {% url 'position_control:teacher_form_add' location_id tab %}
            {% else %}
                {% url 'position_control:teacher_form_edit' location_id fte_assignment.id %}
            {% endif %}
        ">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                {{ form.errors.user }}
                <label for="">{{ form.user.label }}</label>
                {{ form.user }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-2">
                {{ form.errors.room }}
                <label for="">{{ form.room.label }}</label>
                {{ form.room }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-2">
                {{ form.errors.extension }}
                <label for="">{{ form.extension.label }}</label>
                {{ form.extension }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-4">
                {{ form.errors.job }}
                <label for="">{{ form.job.label }}</label>
                {{ form.job }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn ok">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'position_control:teacher_list' location_id %}"><i class="far fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Return to Teacher List</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you share your template? Specifically the section where you are including the disabled `user` field

Comment: @IainShelvington updated original post to contain necessary template information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fields that are required but should not be edited by the user generally you want to hide the field but not disable it

```
    if self.fte_assignment:
        self.fields['user'].widget = forms.HiddenInput
```

Then in your template:

```
{% if form.fte_assignment %}
    {{ form.user }}
{% else %}
    <div class="form-group col-4">
        {{ form.errors.user }}
        <label for="">{{ form.user.label }}</label>
        {{ form.user }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add required=False in the user MultiChoiceField.

```
user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label='Employee',
    required=False,
    queryset=User.objects.all()
```

It means no selection is [required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#required)  for self.fte_assignment is not None Case.
You have Disabled the user field but not set it as blank True in Form level.

Comment: still gives the error when I updated to required = False, this would work if it wasn't a needed field and provided no value to the user field. I still get the original error

Answer (score 0):

Just want to leave my kind of work around solution I came up with to the original question in case it will help anyone in the future. In the template if it is an edit I just made the form render the value of the user field and not the actual field itself.

```
{% if not form.initial %}
    {{ form.errors.user }}
    <label for="">{{ form.user.label }}</label>
    {{ form.user }}
{% else %}
    <label for="">{{ form.user.label }}</label>
    <p>{{ form.initial.user.last_name }}, {{  form.initial.user.first_name }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Then in `forms.py` I made a change to the user field to be defined as:

```
user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    label='Employee',
    required=False,
    queryset=User.objects.all()
)
```

and then I handle cleaning the user field manually. The reason I did the below was for if it is an edit and the fte_assignment has a certain attribute (business requirement I won't get into) the value is never change so I just return it from the object here.

```
 def clean_user(self):
    user = self.cleaned_data.get('user', None)

    # If it is an edit check to see if fte_assingment has assignment so
    # we know we are editing a current year object. If it is current
    # year object just return the user from this method so that it
    # gets set in the request.POST and is valid. This is done because
    # in current year users cannot be edited.
    if self.fte_assignment:
        if hasattr(self.fte_assignment, 'assignment'):
            return self.fte_assignment.assignment.user

    # Manually handle user validation
    if not user:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required.')
    return user
```

I'm not sure how clean of a solution this is but it works for me and obviously any critique is welcome.